# Open source Android chat app that shows nearby users

Tags: android, open-source, chat, gps

I'm searching for an open source Android chat application that shows nearby users, either as List View or on Google Maps using GPS.

To be specific, an app like Peek@U.

Comment: tony k thomas, why did you rollback my edit?

Comment: Not exactly what you want but you can start from [here](https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/)

Comment: Actually, i'm new here and don't know how the site works. sorry if i made some mistake :)

Comment: @tonykthomas: I see -- welcome :) Other users may edit your question to improve it, make it more concise etc. If you don’t agree with specific parts of an edit (e.g., because it changed your intention), just [edit] your question again. If you don’t agree with the *whole* edit, you may rollback your question to the previous revision. -- I removed the "thanks" from your question (it’s usually unnecessary; you may thank users that answer your question by upvoting their answers), and retagged it (we use tags only for *required* features, and you don’t seem to require Google Maps support).

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood your requirement correctly you are looking for something like [Tango](http://www.tango.me/). You can search for users near by and you can also contact people you already know and have their numbers. You can check it out. I honestly haven't evaluate all of it features, I've only used it for calls and video-calls with people I know. Haven't tried the "near me" option.

Comment: Looks interesting, but briefly looking at it it seems to require a lot of permissions, how safe is it really?

Comment: To be honest I can't really say. I've used it only to communicate with friends, and I was adding their profiles via phone number. Never tried the mass chat that's available for it and I had everything as a profile, location and etc disabled. However in the way I've used it, it was safe, that's all I can say out of personal experience. Although some people around me have used all the functionalities of it and have never complained about anything, so I guess is it safe enough to try, just read carefully what do you enable to be visible from everyone.

Comment: P.S. I've last used it couple of years ago, and back then was a bit buggy when trying to have video call. However, it was better than Viber(at the time) for calls.